# Some of good analog of ELK

Tags: logging, monitoring

I am looking for some good open-source or just free system which is an analog of Elastic-Logstash-Kibana(ELK). Could you help me with that question?

It needs to collect and visualization data from some system like ngingx, Oracle, syslogs. I found some example of visualization like [Graphite](https://graphiteapp.org), [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) and [clickhouse](https://clickhouse.yandex). But maybe is there somewhere better examples?

It supposes to be inserted about 1 Tb of Data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At first, it makes sense to look at [Cloud Native Annual Report 2018](https://www.cncf.io/cncf-annual-report-2018/) and using the [CNCF Cloud Native Interactive Landscape](https://landscape.cncf.io/category=logging&format=card-mode&grouping=category) get the recommended paths to resolve your problem.

Probably the [fluentd](https://www.fluentd.org/guides) & [Graylog](https://www.graylog.org/products/open-source) may fit your needs, but take into account [Graylog](https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/graylog2) depends on ElasticSearch and from triad ELK will be removed just LogStash and Kibana.

**ElasticSearch alternatives**

There are many analytic articles about comparing/ranking search engines, for example [DB-Engines Ranking of Search Engines](https://db-engines.com/en/ranking/search+engine).

**Clickhouse**

[Clickhouse](https://clickhouse.yandex/docs/en/) is originally OLAP system, not search text engine such ElasticSearch (just notice that ES built on base [Lucene](https://lucene.apache.org/core/) that was created especially and just for full-text search).

[ClickHouse RoadMap 2019](https://www.altinity.com/blog/clickhouse-roadmap-2019) announces that CH will be more full-text-search-friendly; at this moment this feature has not been released (see [change log](https://github.com/yandex/ClickHouse/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)).

Comment: CNCF is a marketing organization with no real governance or control over the projects which are members. Doesn't compare to someone like Apache. Most logging systems out there are using ElasicSearch and/or Lucene.

Comment: @vladimir, anyway it's a good service to find something, but, as I see, it shows not every distribution, because, I couldn't find *clickhouse* there. And, if Graylog depends on Elastic, anyway, it is also a new variant for me

Comment: @Dred, I extended my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you like ELK? Anyways, give Graylog a shot!

Comment: My manager doesn't want Elk.He said there are problems with that on production. Thank you about graylog. I try to test it now. But it is not free, isn't it?

Comment: They have open source versions. Lots of folks using ELK in production these days never heard of issues. Of course, you need skills on the team, or you should be looking at a service instead. Running any of these open source tools in house is not easy at scale.

Comment: what do you mean under *not easy at scale*?

Comment: All of the open source stacks require a lot of work and skill to run at scale. I'm not sure your requirements, but it can be a challenge. This is why using an ELK service is normally a good idea versus running your own if you expect a high volume of data to ingest and store. If not, then a single node ELK is not difficult.